# Styling SLD Files for Geoserver XML Editors and Notepad++

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am currently using Notebook++ to edit my GeoServer Styles (Yep, I like to do them the hard way). This is a Windows Environment.

I also use XML Copy and XML Notepad 2007 Editor but so far I have been unable to to get a DTD/Schema to work with it for SLD and more specifically the GeoServer Extensions to the SLD Specification.

Questions:

1. Does anyone have a Style for SLD for Notepad++ or know where I can get one?
2. Are there any better XML Editors out there that will use the SLD DTD?
3. Where can I get an XLST file for Geoserver SLD and extensions or vanilla SLDs at the very least

Answer (score 2):

On part 2 of your question, I would recommend [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/index.html). It will happily work with the [SLD schemas](http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/), to allow you to hand craft your styles.